# Generating a new Log file, that contains complete output of a shell script execution, every time shell script executes

Tags: shell

I have one shell script which executes a set of commands.
I want to save the output produced by shell script every time in a new log file.
Log file name should be something like "HealthCheckLogs_date_time".
where date = the date when shell script executes
time = current time in format HH:MM:SS

Please help me generating such a log file for the execution of my shell script.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. :) But what if I want the log file to be created by the shell script itself and execute the script without in redirection. And my script also contains some echo messages for the user to get some input from the user. But when I use redirection, then it is not showing any echo messages from the script because those messages are also redirected to the log file directly. What should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Just call the shell script with output redirected to the log file.

```
#!/bin/sh
datestr=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)
./your_shell_script > HealthCheckLogs_$datestr
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. :) But what if I want the log file to be created by the shell script itself and execute the script without in redirection.

And my script also contains some echo messages for the user to get some input from the user. But when I use redirection, then it is not showing any echo messages from the script because those messages are  also redirected to the log file directly.
What should I do ?

Comment: thus you can make the script to log to the file by itself. first message would be echoed by ">>" and every other message can be appended by echoing by ">".

Answer (score 0):

or it is not necessary

```
 #!/bin/bash   
 datestr=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)   
 echo "Start of the log" > HealthCheckLogs_$datestr  
 ls -la #do something which is not logged.  
 read -p "Input: " -e input  
 echo Your name was $input. > HealthCheckLogs_$datestr  
 echo "End of the log" > HealthCheckLogs_$datestr
```